# su and pipe with variables

Tags: macos, shell, pipe, su

I am writing a shell script, and would like to pipe STDOUT to a file within a su command. The outputted file needs to be owned by another user, hence the use of su. However, I can't get pipe to work with su when the text to be output and the name of the output file are **variables** (see below example).

My workaround is to pipe to a file without using su, then chown that file to the user I need. However, I was wondering if there's a 'single step' way of doing this using su?

Example (for illustration only):

```
#!/bin/sh

message="Hello World";
file="/tmp/HelloWorld.txt";

su someuser -c 'echo "${message}" > "${file}"';
```

If I put `${file}` in double-quotes, as in this example, I get the following error:

```
bash: : No such file or directory
```

If I remove the double-quotes around `${file}`, I get the following error:

```
bash: ${file}: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: Brilliant - it works! And such a quick reply, thanks very much!!

Comment: You "redirect" to a file, and "pipe" to a process.  A regular file is not a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `su someuser -c "echo \"${message}\" > ${file}";`

Variables inside single quotes are not expanded.

Comment: Just a small note that you don't need those escaped double-quotes so make a code look a bit better by removing them (e. g. [...] -c "echo $message > $file").

Comment: @dimir, in general, you need them, or you need to put arguments into single quotes (that would work as well). Consider calling `rm` or any other command instead of `echo`. Without quoting, `rm` would be called with two arguments `Hello`, and `World` while you want a single argument `Hello World`.

Comment: @khachik I ment this particular case as I like to keep code clean and things simple but as a matter of good practice I guess you could leave those. In any case, the semi-colon at the end is not needed. :-)